# Recreating Bing TextBox in WindowsPhone

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-phone-8, richtextbox

[image: text box iamge]

Hello,

I am using Windows Phone 8 (c#) and
I am trying to recreate the TextBox behaviour as seen in the bing app on windows Phone.
The TextBox should look like in the picture, the only problem is if I enter text, i should not be able to enter text past the microphone image

(which is an independent image on top of the textbox -> click on it to use voice recognition).

I dont want to restrict the amount of characters to accomplish that, I want it to behave as if the textbox was just a bit smaller in width.

Does the textbox have any property to do that? I coudn't find one in the documentation so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own template with `Grid` control:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Grid Background="Gray" Margin="5" Width="100">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="23" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                <Image Grid.Column="1"                    
                   Source="http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1742/ecqlipse_2/128/microphone.png" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only problem left is that I cannot get the text to show up in the textbox with you solution. The user clicks on the textbox, the keyboard shows but if you press a key it will not appear in the textbox.

Comment: @user2078645 check my answer again.